# Grpc Conversion issue from RepeatedCompositeContainer to dict

Tags: grpc

RepeatedCompositeContainer

About This I have one question
google._upb._message.RepeatedCompositeContainer' object has no attribute 'file'

this error is coming

I have write this code

convert_dict = MessageToDict(user.results, descriptor_pool=True)

i want to convert RepeatedCompositeContainer into the dict and this is throwing me error as you see

i am expecting to convert RepeatedCompositeContainer to dict

Comment: Your question is unclear. If I understand correctly, you have an object of type `RepeatedCompositeContainer`. Protobuf messages (`m`) cannot be of this type **but** they can have fields (`m.f`) that take this type. If this is your case, you want to apply `MessageToDict` to the message (i.e. `m`) **not** the field (i.e. `m.f`) directly. Once you have the message converted to a dict, you can extract the repreated fields.

Comment: i will post my example then it might get clear

Answer (score 1):

For example:

`foo.proto`:

```protobuf
syntax = "proto3";

package foo;

message X {
    repeated string words = 1;
}
```

And:

```bash
protoc \
--proto_path=${PWD} \
--python_out=${PWD} \
--pyi_out=${PWD} \
${PWD}/foo.proto
```

`main.py`:

```py
from google.protobuf.json_format import MessageToDict

from foo_pb2 import X


x = X()
x.words.extend(["A","B","C"])
print(x)

# Correct (succeeds)
try:
    d=MessageToDict(x)
    print(d["words"])
except AttributeError:
    pass

# Incorrect (fails)
try:
    d=MessageToDict(x.words)
    print(d)
except AttributeError:
    print("unable to convert Message Field to dict")
```

Yields:

```
words: "A"
words: "B"
words: "C"

['A', 'B', 'C']
unable to convert Message Field to dict
```

Comment: NO, it is giving me error

Comment: Thanks, Daz, this helped me understand my problem, which was different, but also involved working with the `RepeatedCompositeContainer`.

Answer (score 0):

```
user.proto

syntax = "proto3";
package user_proto;
import "google/protobuf/empty.proto";
service UserController {
    rpc List(UserListRequest) returns (UserListResponse) {}
}
message User {
    int32 id = 1;
    string name = 2;
    string email = 3;
    string groups = 4;
}
message UserListRequest {
}
message UserListResponse {
    repeated User results = 1;
}

userprotoserializer


from config_routing.models import User
from django_socio_grpc import proto_serializers
from config_routing.grpc import config_routing_pb2

class UserProtoSerializer(proto_serializers.ModelProtoSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        proto_class = user_pb2.User
        proto_class_list = user_pb2.UserListResponse
        fields = '__all__'
       


server.py

def List(self, request, context):
        user = User.objects.using('secondary').all()
        serializer = UserProtoSerializer(user, many=True)
        print(serializer)
        return serializer.message

client.py 

stub = user_pb2_grpc.UserControllerStub(self.channel)
user = stub.List(user_pb2.UserListRequest())
convert_dict = MessageToDict(user)
print(convert_dict["result"])


this shows me error 
AttributeError: file
```

Please look into this issue

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: What do you mean, "please look into this issue"?  You are not reporting a bug to the [protobuf repo](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/issues).  You're asking for a community answer, cutting and pasting your code with no explanation, and what??... expecting an owner from the protobuf repo to find this and respond to it??